# How can I get multiple strings from database between characters

Tags: php, mysql, string, preg-match

So, i have multiple columns formatted like this **`{a|b|c}{e|f|g}{h|i|j}[d]`**.

a,e,h,d are numbers (ex: 2,3,4.5 etc)

b,f,i are dates (ex 1.1.2014 - yes, with dots)

c,g,j is an ID formatted randomly which contain numbers and letters

The column looks like this :

```
{5|1.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}{5.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}{9.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}[7]
```

I ripped my head apart 2 days to figure how to output them in php like this:

**`5 5.25 9.25`** Hovering on each number will show you the date and the user(ID).

I tried with **preg_match** but it will only output me the first {...} or all of them in the same array. So no good thing.

I tried splitting in multiple substrings with a lot of other substrings like this :

```
$i={5|1.1.2014|a23yiuahd3

$i_rest={5.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}{9.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}[7]

$i2={5.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3

$i2_rest={9.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}[7] ,
```

but i got a lot of colums and i overload the database.

On **one** request i wait about 7 seconds.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: have you tried preg_match_all function to get all records in array, than use foreach loop to make output the way you want. http://www.rubular.com/r/8mY6vAn4Yt

Comment: Why do you store data like this in the first place?

Comment: It`s not my db. But ideas are welcomed.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 Write it as an answer so i can upvote. I`ll kill myself. I forgot about preg_match**_all**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, split your string.

```
$s = "{5|1.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}{5.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}{9.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}[7]";
preg_match_all('/{([\d.]+)\|([\d.]+)\|([\da-z]+)}/', $s, $match);

print_r($match);
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {5|1.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}
            [1] => {5.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}
            [2] => {9.25|2.1.2014|a23yiuahd3}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5.25
            [2] => 9.25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.1.2014
            [1] => 2.1.2014
            [2] => 2.1.2014
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => a23yiuahd3
            [1] => a23yiuahd3
            [2] => a23yiuahd3
        )

)
```

Now you can pull out data from an array `$match` and make your own output.